# How do I access the /usr directory on macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

How can I access ALL of the directories in the terminal in macOS? (usr, etc, dev and so on) macOS is hiding them.

Is it possible to access them in the Terminal program on macOS, or does Apple not allow that? If so, do I need to use an aftermarket terminal program?

I can't find the answer to this by Googling it. I just called Apple technical support and they won't tell me how to do it. They said they don't want people messing around in their operating system. I will have to buy another computer eventually, but I just can't afford to right now. If someone would be kind enough to help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "access".  Access to accomplish what purpose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

macOS hides the operating system guts for roughly the same reasons that most buildings have their wiring and plumbing hidden (inside walls and floors): partly 'cause they look ugly, and partly so people won't mess with them and wind up electrocuted and/or with water spraying all over the room. You can certainly expose the OS files on macOS if you want to, but if you mess with them without knowing what you're doing, you're likely to break things. And frankly, if you have to ask this question, you really don't know what you're doing.

You want to mess around anyway? Ok, but start with the assumption that something terrible is going to happen as a result. Do you have any important files on the Mac? Then you'd better back them up somewhere else. One backup is good, two are better (especially if they're in different formats). Also, make an installer disk (follow the [Apple instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), or use [DiskMaker X](http://diskmakerx.com)) so you can erase & reinstall the OS easily if it all goes sideways.

Now, how to get at the hidden files? There are several ways:

1. Use the Terminal application provided with macOS, in the /Applications/Utilities folder. The standard unix commands show the hidden folders you mentioned, but by default they hide files and folders that start with ".". If you want to see those, use `ls -a` (the "-a" means "show [a]ll") or `ls -A` (which shows dotfiles *except* for "." and "..").
2. You can use the Finder to navigate to hidden folders if you know their paths. Choose Go menu > Go to Folder (Command-Shift-G), enter the path you want to go to (e.g. "/etc"), and click Go.
3. Starting in macOS Sierra (v10.12), you can press Command-Shift-Period in the Finder, and it'll toggle visibility of normally-hidden files and folders.

Note that none of these bypass file permissions restrictions. For that, you need something like `sudo` in Terminal, or any of the various operations that the Finder lets you do by entering your admin name & password. There are also some operations that [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) forbids even with an admin override; you can disable this, but [I don't recommend it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really/193379#193379).

Comment: @Codehead Actually, macOS doesn't have a /user directory. There's /Users and /usr (and in recent versions, /home), but no /users. And the only way I know to install Kali with macOS is to partition the drive, and install Kali on a separate partition. You can't install it under macOS, because it's a different OS.

Comment: I did partition my drive, but OSX didn't like it and crashed my machine. I'm going to try to run Metasploit in OSX and see what happens. If it doesn't work, then I'll have to wait until I get a Windows machine. I'm really beginning to dislike Apple....

Comment: Also, I mistakenly typed /user. I meant to type /usr so I just changed my post to reflect that.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm not a troll. I have worked with Linux before and it's easy to find the /usr and other directories that Apple hides on purpose. Even when I called Apple, they wouldn't tell me how to find them because they have intentionally hidden them to prevent users from crashing their computers. Apparently you are the troll here. You gave me a stupid answer that a child could find about Finder. Don't bother responding because I won't be following this thread anymore.